# Can we remove only one element on the localStorage

Tags: javascript

I know that we can remove a group of items with the removeItem(key), but can we remove only one of the value inside? By example I have my key "todo", inside there is `["test1", "test2", "test3"]`, and I want to remove only "test2". How can I do?
The split function isn't working...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post all the relevant code here and also look into [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use `JSON.stringify` when set object to localStorage and `JSON.parse` when `getItem` from localStorage and use `filter` to remove test2 like below

```
let arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(arr));


var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"))

var removedtest2 = stored.filter(c=>c !== 'test2')

localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(removedtest2));
```

```js
let arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(arr));


var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"))

var removedtest2 = stored.filter(c=>c !== 'test2')

localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(removedtest2));
```

Comment: upvoted, but why posted twice?

Comment: one for code snippet and one code bracket :)

Comment: Wow a big thank you it helped me a lot !!!